# EGit pulling from other branches

Tags: github, egit

Im using Egit eclipse plugin. Sometimes when i pull it pulls from other branches too. My expected behaviour is it should pull from the branch im working on. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the default is to [pull only from the upstream branch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch) (instead of "from any branch you want), you could:

- fetch ([everything from upstream](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Fetching_from_other_Repositories))
- [merge the `origin/aBranch` you want to your current branch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Merging_a_branch_or_a_tag_into_the_current_branch).

Answer (score 0):

git branches -> to know the branches from your master

git pull origin (branch name)..

Try this one.